# How do I test for the value of a variable in serverspec

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, serverspec

I have a fairly simple task to complete. I'm writing a number of tests for a Chef project I'm working on. Serverspec gives you resources such as `command`, `file`, etc. What I want to do is simply check for the value of a variable, ie:

```
someVar = "some value dynamically determined"
describe someVar do
   someVar.nil?
end
```

I'm sort of new to ruby, and I'm not exactly sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would just be [standard RSpec](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/an-introduction-to-rspec):

```
describe someVar do
  it { is_expected.to be_nil }
end
```